# First matrix is a Kronecker product. Second is not. Can it be wriyten as a Kronecker product?

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

Can somebody please tell how can I write the matrix system [ b11 b12 0 0; b21 b22 0 0; 0 0 b11 b12; 0 0 b21 b22][u11 u21 u12 u22] into [b11 b12 0 0; 0 0 b11 b12; b21 b22 0 0; 0 0 b21 b22][u11 u12 u21 u22]? Actually I am getting the second matrix but Iwant to get first system. Is there any way to convert the second system into first?

Comment: Please format your mathematical expression correctly, as is [explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/).

Comment: Alternatively, since you're using matlab (or so your syntax indicates), the following sequence of commands would generate the latex output, which you could past into your question: `b = sym('b',[2,2]); z = zeros(1,2); latex([b(1,:), z; z, b(1,:); b(2,:), z; z, b(2,:)])`.  Copy the output, paste it between `$$...$$` to produce
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc} b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & b_{1,1} & b_{1,2}\\ b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} \end{array}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you want to "write" the matrix product
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc} b_{11} & b_{12} & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & b_{11} & b_{12}\\ 
b_{21} & b_{22} & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & b_{21} & b_{22} \end{array}\right)
\pmatrix{u_{11}\\ u_{12}\\ u_{21}\\ u_{22}}
$$
in a different way, but you don't clarify exactly what you mean by that. If we switch the second row and third row, then we have
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc} b_{11} & b_{12} & 0 & 0\\ 
b_{21} & b_{22} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & b_{11} & b_{12}\\  
0 & 0 & b_{21} & b_{22} \end{array}\right)
\pmatrix{u_{11}\\ u_{12}\\ u_{21}\\ u_{22}}.
$$
Perhaps this is what you wanted.